# Using Botan C++ in QT to encrypt files

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, botan

I'm using **`Qt Creator 4.6.1`** on Windows 10
Based on **`Qt 5.10.1 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)`**
Built on **`May 2 2018 04:24:33`**
`qmake` with `mingw491_32`

There is a project from the web which makes use of a `botanwrapper` with the include `Botan.pri`

The full code is quite long so not possible to post here but it is available at http://www.voidrealms.com/index.php?r=source/view&id=1 as a zip file.

That all works and encrypts files but when I bring the files into my my project I get a huge number of compile errors such as those below.

```
botan.h:9380: error: expected identifier before '(' token
          X942_DH_PARAMETERS = ANSI_X9_42,
          ^
```

and `error: expected '}' before '(' token which points to the line`

```
enum Format {
         ANSI_X9_42,
         ANSI_X9_57,
         PKCS_3,

         DSA_PARAMETERS = ANSI_X9_57,
         DH_PARAMETERS = ANSI_X9_42,
         X942_DH_PARAMETERS = ANSI_X9_42, // Error points to here
         PKCS3_DH_PARAMETERS = PKCS_3
      };
```

Also lots of errors relating to the `const` such as

```
error: non-member function 'bool Botan::verify_group(Botan::RandomNumberGenerator&, bool)' cannot have cv-qualifier

bool verify_group(RandomNumberGenerator& rng, bool strong) const;
```

Which points to the code below

---

```
bool verify_group(RandomNumberGenerator& rng, bool strong) const;
```

I have checked the .pro files for the includes and I have the same files setup as the project that compiles and runs on the same setup. I have the same `botan.pri` file included which contains

```
win32 {
    DEFINES += BOTAN_TARGET_OS_IS_WINDOWS \
        BOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_LOADLIBRARY BOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_WIN32_GET_SYSTEMTIME \
        BOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_WIN32_VIRTUAL_LOCK BOTAN_HAS_DYNAMICALLY_LOADED_ENGINE \
        BOTAN_HAS_DYNAMIC_LOADER BOTAN_HAS_ENTROPY_SRC_CAPI BOTAN_HAS_ENTROPY_SRC_WIN32 \
        BOTAN_HAS_MUTEX_WIN32

    win32-msvc* {
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -wd4251 -wd4290 -wd4250
        DEFINES += BOTAN_BUILD_COMPILER_IS_MSVC BOTAN_TARGET_OS_HAS_GMTIME_S
    } else {
        QMAKE_CFLAGS += -fpermissive -finline-functions -Wno-long-long
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -fpermissive -finline-functions -Wno-long-long
    }
    LIBS += -ladvapi32 -luser32
}
```

I have read that removing the `const` will remove 1 or more errors but I don't understand why this is broken on the same setup that happily compiles the `botan.h` and runs the build and encrypts files. Could someone help with how to start to troubleshoot this. Help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Windows API defines a macro `X942_DH_PARAMETERS` which conflicts with this enum. (In fact the enum was renamed in later releases of Botan, to avoid this issue https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues/482).

You can work around it by using `#undef X942_DH_PARAMETERS` before including the Botan headers.

Comment: Jack thanks for this really appreciated I was getting worn down with that. Now I have a strange

`error: undefined reference to `BotanWrapper::DecryptFileW(QString, QString)`

a global search doesn't even show that anywhere in the whole QT project?

Anyway - thanks again!

Comment: Sorry I don't know anything about the Qt wrapper, but one thing to look at is `DecryptFileW` is a Windows API, it is possible Windows header is doing something like `#define DecryptFile DecryptFileW`, so `#undef DecryptFile` may do it.

Comment: Thanks again Jack. I asked on Qt forum but no reply so I posted back to your solution here.

I have just tracked it to the DecryptFile definition in winbase.h so I renamed the botanwrapper to DecryptFileW and that worked. I don't know where the original FileW suffix came from though I have lost track to be honest. I need to consider which is the best way undefine or leave as is and post a clash bug on github for wrapper.

Wish I could award likes/stars/credits here I would throw a bundle your way.